# How to delete colums from view settings on SmartTable?

Tags: sapui5

I would like to delete several columns from view settings on [SmartTable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/overview), after received the data.

For example:

[image]

The fields within the red border should not be available on the view settings. 
I tried as following, but it does not work.

```
var appMode = null;

sap.ui.controller("MA_Reporting.ext.controller.ListReportExt", {

    onInit: function () {

        //Model-Instanz holen       
        var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();

        var oSmartTable = this.getView().byId("listReport");
        oSmartTable.setIgnoredFields("Lo,Lo100,Lo13");

        //var oSmartTable = this.getView().byId("listReport");
        var that = this;

        this._getAppParameters()
            .then(function (oData) {

                appMode = oData.getAppParameters.Appmode;

                var hostname = window.location.hostname;

                var oSmartTable = that.getView().byId("listReport");

                var orgsichtFilter = that.getView().byId("listReportFilter").getAllFilterItems().find(function (oElement) {
                    return oElement.getProperty("name") === "Orgsicht";
                }).getControl();

                if (hostname != "example.com") {

                    // Ausblenden Flag "öffentlich" bei Anlegen von Filter-Varianten
                    that.getView().byId("listReportFilter")._oSmartVariantManagement.setShowShare(false);

                    // Ausblenden Flag "öffentlich" bei Anlegen von Tabellen-Varianten
                    that.getView().byId("listReport")._oVariantManagement.setShowShare(false);

                }

                var variantManagement = that.getView().byId("listReport")._oVariantManagement;

                //Model-Instanz holen       
                var oModel = that.getOwnerComponent().getModel();

                variantManagement.getVariantItems().forEach(function (varItem) {

                    if (varItem.getText() == "liste" && appMode == "FI_ASSI") {
                        variantManagement.removeVariantItem(varItem);
                    }
                });

                // Default-Wert von Dropdown-Liste "Orgsicht" auf "Alle Mitarbeiter" setzen für ASSI-Rolle
                if (appMode == "FI_ASSI") {
                    orgsichtFilter.setSelectedKey("TEST_ASSI_01_");
                    oSmartTable.setIgnoredFields("Lo,Lo100,Lo13");
                }
            }, function (oError) {
                console.log(oError);
            });

    },

    _getAppParameters: function () {
        var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            oModel.callFunction("/getAppParameters", {
                method: "GET",
                urlParameters: null,
                context: null,
                success: function (oData) {
                    resolve(oData);
                },
                error: function (oError) {
                    reject(oError);
                },
            });

        });
    },

    onExit: function () {},

    onBeforeRendering: function () {},

    onAfterRendering: function () {
    }
});
```

As you can see on the code above, the line  `oSmartTable.setIgnoredFields("Lo,Lo100,Lo13");` I am trying to hide the column, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the XML definition of the smartTable, use the attribute ignoreFromPersonalisation and add field name which should not be displayed.
Here is an example:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable
                    id="SmartTableID"
   ignoreFromPersonalisation="Lo,Lo100,Lo13">
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to ignore the columns from Personalisation dynamically? I am currently trying in onBeforeRendering event of the smarttable, but no luck :( says, it is too late because the smarttable is already initialized. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the API:

> setIgnoredFields:
>
> Sets a new value for property ignoredFields.
>   CSV of fields that must be ignored in the OData metadata by the SmartTable control.
>   Note:
>   No validation is done. Please ensure that you do not add spaces or special characters.
>   When called with a value of null or undefined, the default value of the property will be restored.
>
> setIgnoreFromPersonalisation:
>
> Sets a new value for property ignoreFromPersonalisation.
>   CSV of fields that is not shown in the personalization dialog.
>   Note:
>   No validation is done. Please ensure that you do not add spaces or special characters.
>   When called with a value of null or undefined, the default value of the property will be restored.

As you can see the setIgnoreFromPersonalisation does what you inted to do, where the setIgnoredFields methode is about the OData service.

You should always take a look at the API *before* using a new methode or property:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable